Spring batch 5 : bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_TYPE, PARAMETER_VALUE
I was upgrading our app from jdk 11 to 17 and changed the corresponding dependencies. After the upgrade, I am seeing the following error when I run the application,
 org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_TYPE, PARAMETER_VALUE, IDENTIFYING)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 ]

Here is the code,
In application.yml
spring:
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
    job:
      enabled: false
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev3

  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(**********)'
    username:  ******
    password:  *******
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

    
@Configuration
//@EnableBatchProcessing
public class DataLoadJob {


    String tmpFileLocation;

    @Bean
    public Job testJob(Step step1,
                             JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilder("testJob", jobRepository)
                .listener(new JobListener())
                .start(step1) //
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository).tasklet(insertInfo(), transactionManager).build();
    }
}
----------------------------

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.fanniemae.capitalmarkets.cets"})
public class BatchCbdJobApplication implements ApplicationRunner , ExitCodeGenerator {
    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public static final String MODULE = "module";

    private int jobexitCode = 99;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .listeners(new SecretPropertiesListener())
                .properties("spring.config.name:application,queries")
                .sources(BatchCbdJobApplication.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .run(args)
            );

       System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        String moduleName = (args.containsOption(MODULE) || args.getOptionValues(MODULE).size() == 1)
                ?   args.getOptionValues(MODULE).get(0) :"testJob" ;

        try {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addDate(Constants.DATE_TIME_JOB_PARAM, new Date())
                    .addString(MODULE, moduleName)
                    .toJobParameters();

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //jobexitCode = new SimpleJvmExitCodeMapper().intValue(execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());

    }


I referred these links and commented out the annotation @EnableBatchProcessing, still seeing the same error,
Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide
Spring batch - bad SQL grammar
Am I missing any config and How do I fix this? Please let me know if you need any details. Thanks!

Detailed error message:
{"requestTime":"11/08/2024T11:28:12.267","@version":"1","message":"Application run failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_TYPE, PARAMETER_VALUE, IDENTIFYING)\n\tVALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)\n]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:112)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:116)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1548)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:677)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:701)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:1101)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.insertJobParameters(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:431)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:251)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:178)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.lambda$getObject$0(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy113.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59)
at com.batch.BatchJobApplication.run(BatchJobApplication.java:61)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$4(SpringApplication.java:786)
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83)
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60)
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:786)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:149)
at com.batch.BatchJobApplication.main(BatchJobApplication.java:42)\r\nCaused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00904: \"PARAMETER_VALUE\": invalid identifier\n\r\nhttps://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00904/
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.generateBatchUpdateException(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11409)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatchWithoutQueue(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10735)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeBatch(OracleStatement.java:5660)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:292)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:127)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$4(JdbcTemplate.java:1117)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)\r\n\t... 42 common frames omitted\r\n","businessSystemName":"Batch__job","appName":"batch__job"}



Post whole exception. Inner exception may contain more information about error.

Thanks @talexmovedtoCodidact. Updated with detailed error message.

BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS doesn't have PARAMETER_VALUE column. Maybe it was renamed?

The migration guide mentioned that the cloumn changes under the section "Column change in BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS" but didn't look like I have to make any changes regarding that.
Also, the code works for H2 database. I am seeing this error when I use the datasource for Oracle. Not sure if my office network not letting me connect to the DB. Again, the same oracle datasource works fine with jdk11.

Do you use in-memory H2? If so it creates tables on start. Properly setup tables. So you need to find a way to migrate DB Schema.
